# Посетители ru.SO активней чем посетители [en]SO

Tags: обсуждение, цифры

по метрике отношения количества отданных голосов и новых сообщений к посещениям за неделю:

```
>>> votes_ru_per_visit / votes_per_visit:
голоса за принятие        4
голоса «за» и «против»    1.6
голоса «за»               1.5
голоса «против»           2
```

Посетители ru.SO создали в среднем в три раза больше сообщений на визит за последний год.

Отношение всех вопросов за всё время на количество посещений за неделю в полтора раза больше на ru.SO.

Отношение вопросов к ответам и доля принятых ответов примерно одинаковы на обоих сайтах.

Числа в таблице получены с помощью кода на Питоне. Данные с [аналитики сайтов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/site-analytics) за год:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import pandas

votes = pandas.read_csv('votes_2016-Sep-13_2017-Sep-13_weekly.csv').mean()
traffic = pandas.read_csv('traffic_2016-Sep-13_2017-Sep-13_weekly.csv').mean()
votes_per_visit = votes / traffic.visits

votes_ru = pandas.read_csv('ru/votes_2016-Sep-13_2017-Sep-13_weekly.csv').mean()
traffic_ru = pandas.read_csv('ru/traffic_2016-Sep-13_2017-Sep-13_weekly.csv').mean()
votes_ru_per_visit = votes_ru / traffic_ru.посещения
votes_per_visit.rename(index={
     'accept votes': 'голоса за принятие',
     'downvotes': 'голоса «против»',
     'up and down votes': 'голоса «за» и «против»',
     'upvotes': 'голоса «за»'},
                       inplace=True)
print(votes_ru_per_visit / votes_per_visit)
```

Comment: Программирование набирает обороты, в будущем человек будет не человеком если не будет программировать. Сейчас все больше появляется роботов и других устройств которых в случае программной неисправности приходится изменять код программы устройства. Да и это еще и деньги, тот же фриланс если не сложно заметить, больше всего вопросов по _Javascript_, что является востребованным языком программирования для людей нуждающийся в веб ресурсе. Тем более во многих современных школах появился урок информатики и нынешнее поколение примерно по статистике 25% это зацепляет.  Фух чуть символы не кончились...

Comment: А если честно то в России много _"Васей Пупкиных"_ которые хотят срубить бабла на веб ресурсах с кодом соответствующей этой фразе: _"Костыль за костылем ради костыля"_.

Comment: @Duoxx, и какое отношение ваши комментарии имеют к теме исходного сообщения (активность посетителей двух разделов StackOverflow)?

Comment: Я сказал  то что я думаю.

Comment: @Duoxx, "больше всего вопросов по Javascript" - удобно что можно просто добавить метку в игнорируемые, и не видеть эти вопросы. Это я так, к слову.

Comment: @Duoxx: в богатых странах [Питон самая посещаемая метка сейчас](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/09/06/incredible-growth-python/?cb=1), в других странах javascript+java близки, но питон резво растёт.

Answer (score 6):

Я считаю, что дело в обилии специализированных англоязычных ресурсов: askUbuntu, Unix & Linux и много других, в то время, как русскоязычный такой ресурс один.

Comment: Как это связано что больше голосов, сообщений на посещение? (Посещение это что-то вроде просмотра SO вопроса с ip за ~15 минут) Прозаичнее объяснение, что у английского SO больше доля незалогиненных посетителей, которые просматривают вопросы не голосуя, не задавая вопросов, не отвечая на вопросы.

Answer (score 0):

> по метрике отношения количества отданных голосов и новых сообщений к посещениям за неделю

говорит только о том, что на англоязычном сайте уже набран корпус готовых ответов, а на русскоязычном проще задать новый, чем прочесть существующий.

Comment: 1- это не объясняет почему *голосуют* меньше. 2- если их блог почитать, то данные говорят, что вопросы не заканчиваются, нет насыщения. Иначе говоря, больше вопросов за период означает большее использование технологии. Отсутствие вопросов не говорит, что все вопросы уже задали, всё ясно, а говорит что не пользуются технологией. ["Conclusion: do questions really represent the health of a technology?"](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/08/01/flash-dead-technologies-might-next/).

Comment: голосуют меньше просто потому что не все посетители залогинены. Впрочем, спорить с самовнушениями вида "мы такие белые ипушистые, а главное белее ипушистее их" бессмысленно, так что я удаляюсь

Comment: Вы написали: "набран  корпус готовых ответов" что отличается от "незалогинены", как [я выше написал](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5909/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8-ru-so-%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8-enso/5915#comment22651_5915). С фактами бесполезно спорить. Если вы думаете что цифры ошибочны, то данные и код доступны, можете сами посчитать. Объяснение этих фактов, это уже другое дело. "Белые и пушистые" это вы от себя добавили.

Comment: чувак. только что я одному нубу преподавал азы логики на основном сайте. тебе тоже не помешает. если ты дашь себе труд прочитать мой ответ, там ничего нет про голоса. **поэтому** "набран корпус готовых ответов" и отличается от "незалогинены". А объяснение фактов - это да, это святое. "Русскоязычные пользователи более  лучше активны", ага. У таракана уши в ногах.