# Какие технологии используют разработчики из Франции?

Tags: обсуждение, перевод-блога

Разработка ПО - глобальная индустрия, и программисты во всех уголках мира используют Stack Overflow для решения их проблем. Логично, что в разных странах используются различные ЯП и технологии. Ранее уже был [подобный пост про Германию](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/09/26/software-developers-use-germany/?utm_source=so-owned&utm_medium=blog&utm_campaign=gen-blog&utm_content=blog-link&utm_term=software-developers-france), где мы показали, что в Германии люди посещают разделы [c](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) and [c++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) чаще, чем в остальном мире.

В этой статье мы рассмотрим программистов из Франции, какие технологии и языки они используют, как отличается от остального мира, как отличается внутри самой страны.

Вся аналитика основания на данных за 2017 год. Мы также [обнаружили](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/08/29/tale-two-industries-programming-languages-differ-wealthy-developing-countries/?utm_source=so-owned&utm_medium=blog&utm_campaign=gen-blog&utm_content=blog-link&utm_term=software-developers-france), что страны с высоким уровнем дохода ([по данным World Bank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Bank_high-income_economy)) показывают различные паттерны посещаемых технологий. В этих странах чаще посещают [python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) и [r](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r), реже [android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) и [php](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php), чем в остальном мире. Если сравнивать Францию с остальным миром, мы наблюдаем похожую картину. Поэтому, в этой статье мы сосредоточимся на сравнении трафика от разработчиков из Франции с разработчиками из остальных стран с высоким доходом (в основном США, Великобритании, Канады и Германии).

Франции принадлежит 2.91% от всех посещений вопросов Stack Overflow, что ставит её на 6 место по трафику в мире. Также ей принадлежит 2.49% трафика по ответам (6 в мире) и написании ответов (5 место).

## Языки и технологии

Языки и технологии, которые используются разработчиками, отражают потребности отрасли. С чем чаще всего работают разработчики из Франции, с чем реже по сравнению с остальным миром?

[image: Использование технологий во Франции]

Как видно по графику, [php](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) - одна из самых посещаемых меток во Франции, наравне с [hibernate](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hibernate) ORM для Java. Некоторые другие метки, имеющие отношение к веб-разработке, такие как [angular](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular)/[angularjs](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs) и [typescript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typescript) также посещаются чаще, чем в остальном мире. Это может означать, что веб-разработка необычно распространена во Франции по сравнению с другими видами программирования. Наличие [apache](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache), [docker](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docker) и [ubuntu](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu) также может означать распростаннёность системных администраторов или инженеров DevOps.

Интересно, что почти все недопредставленные теги - это технологии Microsoft, в том числе SQL Server, ASP.NET и Excel. Похожая картина и в Германии, обе страны реже испольуют стек Microsoft. Фактически, Германия и Франция входят в число стран, которые посещают ASP.NET реже всего по сравнению с остальным миром (страны, в которых очень часто посещается ASP.NET часто включают Великобританию, Индию и Бразилию).

## Статистика по городам

В нашем последнем анализе мы сравнили теги, которые посещали из двух крупнейших городов Германии - Берлина и Мюнхена. В данном случае это не так полезно, т.к. во франции посещения по большей части из Парижа и его пригорода. Шестьдесят процентов трафика французского Stack Overflow поступает из района вокруг Парижа в радиусе 50 миль (другие крупнейшие города, такие как Лион и Тулуза, составляют около 5%), что неудивительно, потому что именно здесь сосредоточена большая часть населения. (Исключением является Марсель, который составляет лишь 3% трафика, несмотря на то, что он является вторым по величине городом Франции).

Как Париж отличается от остальной Франции с точки зрения посещаемых меток?

[image: Сравнение Парижа с остальной Францией]

Париж, безусловно, является финансовым центром Франции: [excel](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel) посещается намного чаще, чем из остальной части страны, наряду с [pandas](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas). Наличие нескольких связанных с Microsoft тегов, таких как SQL Server и ASP.NET, предполагает, что, хотя использование стека Microsoft относительно редко встречается во Франции, они посещаются в основном из Парижа.

Ранее мы видели, что во Франции [php](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) посещается чаще, чем остальная часть мира с высоким доходом, и этот график показывает, что большая часть трафика идёт из-за пределов Парижа (из самого Парижа посещений на 25%, чем с остальной части страны). Если [php](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) не так часто посещают в Париже, то откуда его посещают? Мы можем сравнить объем трафика посещений [php](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) для каждого города.

[image: Посещение php по городам]

PHP составляет 5,33% трафика Парижа, что немного выше среднего для стран с высоким доходом, но это один из самых низких процентов по сравнению с любым другим городом Франции. Французские города, такие как Лион и Марсель, очень часто посещают [php](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php). Города, из которых посещений меньше, такие как Тулуза и Брест, обычно являются университетскими (PHP редко используется студентами и для научных исследований).

Если вы разработчик из Франции, находитесь вы в Париже или любом другом городе страны, и хотите сделать следующий шаг в вашей карьере, вот несколько компаний, которые [ищут сотрудников во Франции прямо сейчас](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?sort=i&l=France&d=20&u=Miles&utm_source=so-owned&utm_medium=blog&utm_campaign=gen-blog&utm_content=blog-link&utm_term=software-developers-france) на Stack Overflow Jobs.

---

<sub>Свободный перевод публикации [«What Do Software Developers Use in France?»](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/01/30/software-developers-use-france/).</sub>

Comment: Любопытно, но хотелось бы ещё и подобной статистики по России.

Comment: @AK у высокозаплюсованных пользователей ru SO есть доступ к гугл аналитике. Возможно кто-то из них мог бы статью по ru SO сделать. Или вы именно про Российский трафик на en SO.

Comment: @Suvitruf /site-analytics разбиение по странам не показывает. Из интересного: ~95% траффика это поиск. После гугла, основной источник это yandex.ru всё остальное по мелочь. Доступна информация по количеству голосов, сообщений. Пример использования [Посетители ru.SO активней чем посетители \[en\]SO](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5909/23044)